# Interaction effect when both variables negative

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, interaction

I am trying to create a regression model.

Through experience with the subject matter I think there should be a effect on **y** when 2 of my variables **x1 and x2** are both largely negative.

**x1 and x2** have been standardized and centered.

I think there will be an effect on **y** only when both of these are are large negative numbers, I am trying to capture this with an interaction term.  The problem I am running into is when **x1*x2** are both negative the product is positive.

For example,  **x1 and x2** both equaling -5, gives +25 for the interaction term which would be treated the same as if they were both equal to 5.

How do I go about approaching this?

Comment: There are some terms not very accurately stated. But if I understand correctly, you can consider signed interaction like this $x_1I(x_1 < 0) \times x_2 I(x_2 < 0)$.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this and self teaching myself at the moment.  Is this basically an interaction term that you would only add in when both **x1 and x2** are negative?

Comment: "$I_A(x)$" means an *indicator function* of a set $A$: it equals to $1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \notin A$. It may also be written as $I(x \in A)$ as I gave above. For example, if $x = -5$, then $I(x < 0) = 1$, while if $x = 5$, then $I(x < 0) = 0$.

Comment: ok so is this essentially turning both into dummy variables either a 1 or a 0?

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are still in it. It becomes $0$ when either $x_1$ or $x_2$ is positive.

Comment: I will try this, thank you!